# Why is this lisp benchmark (in sbcl) so slow?

Tags: common-lisp, performance-testing, sbcl

Since I’m interested in C++ as well as in Lisp, I tried to reproduce the benchmark presented [here](https://orilla.fr/2016/03/20/is-common-lisp-suitable-for-simple-numerical-computations/) written by Guillaume Michel. The benchmark is basically a DAXPY BLAS Level 1 operation performed multiple times on big arrays. The full code was thankfully posted on [github](https://github.com/guillaume-michel/bench-saxpy) and is in both languages roughly one page.

Sadly, I discovered that it was not possible for me to reach the velocity of his calculations for lisp.

For Linux, he got similar results for C++ as well as Lisp:

> Size | C++ | Common Lisp
>
> 100,000,000 | 181.73 | 183.9

The numbers differ (naturally) both on my PC:

> Size | C++ | Common Lisp
>
> 100,000,000 | 195.41 | 3544.3

Since I wanted an additional measurement, I started both programs with the `time` command and got (shortened up):

```
$ time ./saxpy
real    0m7.381s
$ time ./saxpy_lisp
real    0m40.661s
```

I assumed different reasons for this blatant difference. I scanned through both code samples, but found no big algorithmic or numeric difference between the C++ and Lisp Version. Then I thought, the usage of `buildapp` created the delay, so I started the benchmark directly in the REPL. My last resort was to try another version of `sbcl`, so I downloaded the newest `sbcl-1.3.11` and evaluated it there – still the (optimized) Lisp version needs much longer than it’s C++ counterpart.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you compile the Lisp code?

Comment: I tried (load "lispfile") from within the REPL, --load from the bash and tried both with the compiled (?) file.fasl file

Comment: The `.fasl` file is the compiled version.

Comment: Make sure you set the best compiler optimization settings with `(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))` when compiling

Comment: Yes, these are in the important functions (see github code). I also tried to set it globally (like you suggested) – no big difference

Comment: Then I don't know how to explain your results. When you disassemble the function, does it look similar to the code in the paper?

Comment: Well the output is on [nopaste](https://nopaste.me/view/2de51fdb), I'm no expert but to me it looks similar

Comment: Then there's no good reason why your test should be 20x slower. There must be a problem with your timing methodology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot replicate your findings:

```
sylwester@pus:~/a/bench-saxpy:master$ sbcl --dynamic-space-size 14000
This is SBCL 1.3.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (compile-file "saxpy.lisp")

; compiling file "/pussycat/natty-home/westerp/apps/bench-saxpy/saxpy.lisp" (written 06 NOV 2016 12:04:30 AM):
; compiling (DEFUN SAXPY ...)
; compiling (DEFUN DAXPY ...)
; compiling (DEFMACRO TIMING ...)
; compiling (DEFUN BENCH ...)
; compiling (DEFUN MAIN ...)

; /pussycat/natty-home/westerp/apps/bench-saxpy/saxpy.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.038
#P"/pussycat/natty-home/westerp/apps/bench-saxpy/saxpy.fasl"
NIL
NIL
* (load "saxpy.fasl")

T
* (main t)
Size, Execution Time (ms)
10, 0.0
100, 0.0
1000, 0.0
10000, 0.1
100000, 0.49999997
1000000, 3.6
10000000, 39.2
100000000, 346.30002
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

So on my machine it took 346ms (relatively old machine). The whole test took about 5 seconds but that is a series of many tests. Interesting that running from sbcl was faster than making an image and running it:

```
sylwester@pus:~/a/bench-saxpy:master$ make lisp
buildapp --output saxpy_lisp --entry main --load saxpy.lisp --dynamic-space-size 14000
;; loading file #P"/pussycat/natty-home/westerp/apps/bench-saxpy/saxpy.lisp"
[undoing binding stack and other enclosing state... done]
[saving current Lisp image into saxpy_lisp:
writing 4944 bytes from the read-only space at 0x20000000
writing 3168 bytes from the static space at 0x20100000
writing 60522496 bytes from the dynamic space at 0x1000000000
done]
sylwester@pus:~/a/bench-saxpy:master$ ./saxpy_lisp 
Size, Execution Time (ms)
10, 0.0
100, 0.0
1000, 0.0
10000, 0.0
100000, 0.4
1000000, 3.5
10000000, 40.2
100000000, 369.49997
```

In the C version I get:

```
100000000, 296.693634, 295.762695, 340.574860
```

It seems like the C version actually calculates the same in 3 different ways and reports the time it took. Using `time` wouldn't do it justice.

Comment: First of all: thank you very much for taking the time and replicating. Second: I did *exactly* the same steps you did, but did encounter many notes like `note: forced to do GENERIC-* (cost 30)` and `note: forced to do GENERIC-+ (cost 10)` while compiling the functions `daxpy` and `saxpy`. Did you remove them in your post? And: already with 10000 steps I have 0.7 in constrast to your 0.0 – so even there is some difference. And I should mention I've quite a new mashine, so I'd expect faster output…

Comment: @claudio I included all output and used only the git repo. I did the same on my mac and it was much faster, about 208ms following the first procedure since I don't have `buildapp`. The message you get is mentioned in a [lispforum post](http://www.lispforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3204)

Comment: Okay, I downloaded your version (`sbcl-1.3.1`), and again replicated your steps. With that, no compiler notes, also velocity now *much* faster. I think, that answers my original question – the reason for the slowness lies in the version of sbcl. I will mark your answer as solution to my problem and turn this to the developers of sbcl. Thank you again!

Comment: @claudio The SBCL-version I used when I tested on macOs was 1.3.11 so it might not be the same regression on all platforms. Also, both of my machines were 64 bit while the note on result not being fixnum indicates you might be using a 32 bit machine?

Comment: No, I have a 64 bit machine. I have tried the benchmark on my laptop, 32bit, `sbcl-1.3.6`, and also get compiler notes and slow benchmark.

Comment: Update! The sbcl developers looked over it and it was something in the mapping `map-into`. Nevertheless, this issue is solved in the newest current version `sbcl-1.3.11`. I downloaded this and tried on both 32- and 64-bit machines. No compiler warnings and a fast benchmerk